# Multiple IP configuration on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to extract data from a server which is limited to a number of requests per IP. I don't want to make another instance so i thought i could use multiple IP Address on same instance. Right now, I have one Elastic IP address associated with my instance and i am hosting a website on it. To extract data on the server I don't want to use the same IP so i attached another IP address to it. So i have 2 IP address, one is elastic and other is not. I am running a t2.micro EC2 Instance and using the Free tier provided by AWS. I read the docs again and again and did some extra reading too but i am still not clear on how to use those IP address. It says that i am limited to 5 IP per instance(limit can be increased if u want though) but it's not clear about the pricing. I want to ask whether associating another IP address to the instance cost something or not? My instance is up and running 24*7 so no charges about IP address associated with a non-running instance. The docs do specify about elastic IP but not non-elastic multiple IP.

Comment: The best people to ask about Amazon's pricing structure are, surprisingly, Amazon.

Comment: @MadHatter I have been trying that from last 1 hour. All the officials tells me about is Elastic IP Addresses pricing not public IP addresses, that's the reason i posted. I thought maybe somebody may have an answer and save me a lot of headache.

Comment: Elastic IPs **are** public IPs.

Comment: @EEAA yes i know

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about abusing someone's network via AWS.

Comment: @FalconMomot the site doesn't have a robots.txt, not my problem.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be a recalcitrant malfeasor and justify it that way, go right ahead I suppose.  Booooo.

Comment: @FalconMomot can you stop abusing man?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work for Amazon and take no responsability about pricing (especially because the pricing structure for Amazon gets more complicated every day that goes ) but:

Elastic IPs are "free" as long as they are attached to an instance (hence the limit of 5 or people would just consume the whole space AWS has)

If you want to use 2 Elastic IPs on a single instance then you will need 2 private ips on your instance. Each EIP must be associated to a Private IP (being just a simple 1-to-1 NAT) and only one EIP can be associated to a Pribate IP at any time.

You can have multiple NIC each of them with 2 IP on an EC2 Instance, even though the multiple NIC are only available in VPC i believe.

Last but not least, by using IAM Roles to grant permissions to your instance, you could manage those EIP from the instance itself, including a regular refresh of them if changing IP is a requirement for your application to work.